# List Array view all entries in TextView

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList which get all it's entries as strings from DB

```
List<Amthal> amthal = getAmthalSetFromDb(p);
```

I can get it's size "how many strings it contains"

```
int i= amthal.size();
```

I want to view these strings in TextView one after the another by clicking next button to move to next one

I tried to view any string in that array list but I got an error… "get(i-1)" which must return last string in that array …

```
    tv.setText(amthal.get(i-1));
```

my question is how to retrieve and view these strings ? should I convert it to Array of strings or what??

Comment: Please post the full error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your issue by using an counter varaible as :

```
public static int count=0;  //Declare it as class level varaible
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if(count < amthal.size())
         {
              tv.setText(amthal.get(count).toString()); //set textView Text here
              count++;  // increase counter here
         }
         else{
            //Reset counter to 0
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: it shows in text view when test on mobile com.example.com.testdb.Amthal@40dcd678 where com.example.com.testdb is my package name , and Amthal is my table in my DB ,, where that string 40dcd678 changes when i click next button seems showing it in ascci !

Comment: means your Array list contain wrong value. .i think you will need to check ArrayList Values retrieved from database is right

Comment: I only tried to "set textView" , and now it's working fine but when I tried to use your solution with the next button , here is some warnings "Illegal modifier for parameter count; only final is 
 permitted"

Comment: where you have declared count variable? declare it as class level variable instead of method level